# Hard Link for Directories in linux

Tags: linux, backup, rhel5, directory, hardlink

Hai,

- How can i create hard link for my directories ?
- When i use to make link from /var to /home it shows error on "Invalid cross-device link", How can i over come it ?

Comment: Links aren't backups; they're just pointers to the original file.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only make symbolic links to directories.

From `man 7 symlink`:

```
       Hard links may not refer to directories (to pre‐
       vent the possibility of loops within the file system tree, which  would
       confuse  many  programs)  and  may not refer to files on different file
       systems (because i-node numbers are not unique across file systems).
```

To make backups, use `rsync`, `dd` or `cpio` (sometimes together with `tar`, `bzip2`, `gzip` or `zip`).

Answer (score 0):

By using the

```
ln
```

command.

[Read this](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln) for more info.

Comment: whoops. see above...

Comment: "Operation not permitted" i got this error when using "ln -d ". Is there any other way to overcome this ?

Comment: @Kumar: From `man ln`: "(note: will  probably  fail  due  to  system restrictions, even for the superuser)"